# Go and Pointers in http middleware

Tags: go, pointers, go-chi

I'm trying to log some data on my web server, so I created a `loggingMiddleware` that serves the next request and then logs the data, I thought this way I would have all the necessary data inside the `r *http.Request` pointer

```golang
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // call next handler
        next.ServeHTTP(o, r)

        // get requestID
        reqID := middleware.GetReqID(r.Context())

        log.WithFields(
            log.Fields{
                "request_id":     reqID,           // drops requestID
                "method":         r.Method,        // http method
                "remote_address": r.RemoteAddr,    // remote address
                "url":            r.URL.String(),  // url used by the client to access the service
                "referer":        r.Referer(),     // Referer header if present
                "user_agent":     r.UserAgent(),   // User-Agent header
                "content_length": r.ContentLength, // Content-Length header if present"
            },
        ).Info()
    })
```

However for the RequestID this is true only if the `RequestID` middleware is mounted before the loggingMiddleware

Non-Working

```golang
...
    // get a new chi rotuter
    router = chi.NewRouter()

    // MIDDLEWARES

    // log
    // use logrus to log requests
    router.Use(LoggingMiddleware)

    // requestID
    // Generate a unique id for every request
    // ids are grouped based on client hostname
    router.Use(middleware.RequestID)
...
```

Working

```golang
...
    // get a new chi rotuter
    router = chi.NewRouter()

    // MIDDLEWARES

    // requestID
    // Generate a unique id for every request
    // ids are grouped based on client hostname
    router.Use(middleware.RequestID)

    // log
    // use logrus to log requests
    router.Use(LoggingMiddleware)
...
```

Is this the expected behavior? Should the `r *http.Request` pointer point to the "updated" version of the request? Is there a way to get around this?
Because if I want, for example, extract a username from a JWT token and put it in the `r.Context()` so I can log it later, this would require a separate middleware to be mounted before the `loggingMiddleware`.

Sorry for my english, please ask if there's something not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`middleware.RequestID` adds the request ID to the request context by using `http.Request.WithContext`:

```
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, RequestIDKey, requestID)
next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
```

Per the documentation:

> WithContext returns a shallow copy of r with its context changed to
> ctx. The provided ctx must be non-nil.

Therefore, because it "returns a shallow copy of r", and it is (a pointer to) this shallow copy which it passes to `next.ServeHTTP`, if `middleware.RequestID` is mounted second, then the `r` in `LoggingMiddleware` is pointing to a different `*http.Request` than the one which contains the modified context, and so its context will not contain the request ID. If, on the other hand, `middleware.RequestID` is mounted first, then `LoggingMiddleware` will receive a pointer to the shallow copy that `r.WithContext` returned, and everything will work as expected.